# Can not set FOREIGN KEY with DELETE ON CASCADE

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I would like delete referencing data with a FOREIGN KEY.

Here are two of my datatables:

```
CREATE TABLE `specification_variant_parent` (
  `specification_variant_parent_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sort_order` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`specification_variant_parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE `specification_variant_parent_description` (
  `specification_variant_parent_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `language_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`specification_variant_parent_id`,`language_id`),
  KEY (`specification_variant_parent_id`)
  REFERENCES specification_variant_parent (specification_variant_parent_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

When I fire it in phpMyAdmin it says:

> Error in foreign key constraint of table
>   database/specification_variant_parent_description: FOREIGN KEY
>   (`specification_variant_parent_id`)   REFERENCES
>   specification_variant_parent (specification_variant_parent_id) ON
>   DELETE CASCADE ) ENGINE=InnoDB: Cannot find an index in the referenced
>   table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns, or
>   column types in the table and the referenced table do not match for
>   constraint.

What is wrong with my database scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datatypes do not match.

In the first table you have

```
`specification_variant_parent_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMEN
```

The datatype you declare is an unsigned int

In the second table the foreign key is

```
`specification_variant_parent_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL
```

and the datatype is an unsigned smallint

Make both of them the same datatype.

Comment: Sometimes little things makes the difference. Many thanks for your help. Next time I will check it better.